# android constraint layout alignment between textview and edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I need to put a `TextView` and `EditText` in the same line within constraint layout and keep it align each other! below code generate a picture like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serverIpAddr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="192.168.1.11"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serverPort"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="8080"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/serverIpAddr"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now it looks ugly, the TextView and EditText log align horizontally correctly, TextView a little bit above EditText

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` attribute to make the text of both horizontally aligned

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serverIpAddr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="192.168.1.11"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/serverPort"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Great, if I have multiple element in one line, how can I align all of them to the same baseline? I am thinking about one by one to align baseline but maybe it's not proper method!

Comment: @lucky1928 are those elements text based views like `TextView` ? or do you have something else like ImageView's

Comment: It's a imageView!

Comment: You give the [GuideLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) a try, it's a virtual view within ConstraintLayout that you can align views to it